# wings communication server: submitsm command status 0x14

Tags: sms, wcs

Has anyone had experience with this tool (WCS). Some sms messages are not being sent. The log says:

```
2007-04-14 10:59:53,490 [logica-smpp2-receiver] ERROR logica-smpp2 - Message not sent, SubmitSM command status: 0x14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've read the specs correctly, command status 0x14 means "message queue full".

I suggest:
- Try spreading the messages over a longer period
- Ask your SMPP provider what the limits are, how many messages can you send in how much time? Make the appropriate changes in the calls, or ask them to increase the amount of messages you can send for a given time period.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thanks.